# General CS: Lexicographical Order

Tags: computer-science

Simple one, but looking for a sanity check. If I'm asked to find the lexicographically smallest list - this has nothing to do with the actual length of the list, right? It's just element wise comparison where [0,7] would be lexicographically smaller than [7,7], for example? Thanks very much!

Comment: I wouldn’t say it has _nothing_ to do with length, as length becomes meaningful when two lists are otherwise identical (`[0]` is smaller than `[0,0]`).  But I believe your understanding is correct.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I was confused on - I was trying to decide between a list of [0,7] and [7] on which was smaller. Thank you!!

Comment: In that example, I believe `[0,7]` would precede `[7]` in the same way `AX` would precede `X` in alphabetical ordering.

Comment: From Wiipedia: *To compare sequences of different lengths, the shorter sequence is usually padded at the end with enough "blanks" (a special symbol that is treated as smaller than every element of A). This way of comparing sequences of different lengths is always used in dictionaries.* In CS, this is the convention used.